# How to modify Sawtooth fishnet website and check logs?

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

Hello I want to modify the labels and the content of the fishnet app, also I want to look into the logs of the system, how I can do that?
Right now I've installed in docker but is impossible to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hello I want to modify the labels and the content of the fishnet app ..

Mainly, you can find all codes for Fishnet app client [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain/tree/5d9b76e5f8e18fb6180fc449c77851e8fff100fa/fish_client/src). You can find the navigation app labels of the fishnet app in the [main.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain/blob/5d9b76e5f8e18fb6180fc449c77851e8fff100fa/fish_client/src/main.js). Inside there, you can modify the labels by changing the string 'Add Fish', 'View Fish', 'Profile', etc. Secondly, please take a look files inside [Components folder](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain/tree/5d9b76e5f8e18fb6180fc449c77851e8fff100fa/fish_client/src/components) and [views folder](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain/tree/5d9b76e5f8e18fb6180fc449c77851e8fff100fa/fish_client/src/views) if you want to modify the the content.

> I want to look into the logs of the system, how I can do that?

The easiest way to see all logs in the system is by looking at [Docker Dashboard](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/dashboard/) . You could also check all logs of the system using [docker logs command](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/).